# Does Notification Cloud URI have any limits?

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, push-notification, mpns

I have working with Push Notification  in WindowsPhone. I'm able to send the Notification from the server  and receive it in Windows Phone. 
I'm using the url for cloud generated by the below code. Does any of you guys knows is there any limitation for this url like time limit or licensing etc.. 
Since when my app is get launched we need to create n no of url for the every user.

/// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
            HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

```
        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

        InitializeComponent();

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for toast events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        }

        Thanks in advance. 
        Thanks
        Kamal.
```

Comment: Please, show your xml, that server sends to MSNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, there are only three limits with Push Notifications:

1. MPNS allows both unauthenticated and authenticated notifications. However, unauthenticated push requests are throttled if they exceed 500 messages per day (per device). There are no such restrictions on authenticated requests which uses client SSL for authentication.
2. 1 notification channel per application
3. Maximum notification channels on device are 30

Comment: Hi, thanks. But i need to have both Tile and Toast notification for my app. I have tried with Same url for both Notification using BindtoToast() and bindToTile() but it does't works. Do i need to have an separate url for Tile and Toast. Please let me know.

Comment: No, one url for all Notifications